# Auto-layout with constraintsWithVisualFormat is not working well

Tags: ios, swift, ios-autolayout

I have Set scrollview and add constraints to scrollview. But it is showing blank screen. Please check below code.

```
override func loadView()
    {
        super.loadView()
        scrollView = UIScrollView(frame:CGRectZero)
        scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        scrollView.sizeToFit()

        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

        contentView = UIView()
//        contentView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)

        var viewBindingsDictBoth = [String: AnyObject]()
        viewBindingsDictBoth["scrollView"] = scrollView
        viewBindingsDictBoth["contentView"] = contentView
        viewBindingsDictBoth["mainView"] = self.view


        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[scrollView]-0-|",options: [], metrics: nil,  views:viewBindingsDictBoth))

        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[scrollView]-0-|",options: [], metrics: nil, views:viewBindingsDictBoth))

        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[contentView]|",options: [], metrics: nil, views:viewBindingsDictBoth))
        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[contentView]|",options: [], metrics: nil, views:viewBindingsDictBoth))

        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[contentView(==mainView)]",options: [], metrics: nil, views:viewBindingsDictBoth))

        self.view.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Redraw
    }
```

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Are you seeing any warnings in the console when running this?

Comment: You cannot have a constraint between `self.view` (`mainView`) and `contentView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important thing you are missing is

```
scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

and

```
contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

I think that some of your constraints are not perfect but the biggest problem is that every view is using its autoresizing properties for positioning by default. Those will then collide with your constraints.

From [UIView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints):

> Note that the autoresizing mask constraints fully specify the view’s size and position; therefore, you cannot add additional constraints to modify this size or position without introducing conflicts. If you want to use Auto Layout to dynamically calculate the size and position of your view, **you must set this property to false**, and then provide a non ambiguous, nonconflicting set of constraints for the view.

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 1):

I usually find it very unnecessary to override `loadView` unless I'm really trying to get the base view (`self.view`) to be of a different subclass of UIView. `loadView` is for initializing the value of `self.view`, which you have forgotten to do.

In your case, for legibility I would recommend moving view initialization to `viewDidLoad`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    // Do your init here
}
```

Comment: I think that `super.loadView()` will generate a view. It would crash anyway if `view` were `nil`.

Comment: @Sulthan That is incorrect. According to the doc "Your custom implementation of this method should not call super"

Comment: The recommendation is logical because the whole point of the method is to create a view therefore calling `super` to create another view does not make sense. However, if you call `super.loadView()`, you can then use `self.view` and it will work because the original implementation will create a `UIView` instance.

Comment: I know that, I am trying to explain you why and that the bug of the OP is not caused by that.

Answer (score 0):

In loadView() method of your viewcontroller you need create a root view. Your root view right now is nil 
 `view = UIView()`

Answer (score 0):

You have a few mistakes:

```
    override func loadView()
        {
            super.loadView()
            scrollView = UIScrollView(frame:CGRectZero)
            scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            scrollView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

            // No need for sizeToFit with autoLayout
            //scrollView.sizeToFit()

            self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
            scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

            contentView = UIView()

           //Always set TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false, on every view that users AutoLayout

            contentView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
            contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            scrollView.addSubview(contentView)

            var viewBindingsDictBoth = [String: AnyObject]()
            viewBindingsDictBoth["scrollView"] = scrollView
            viewBindingsDictBoth["contentView"] = contentView
            viewBindingsDictBoth["mainView"] = self.view


            view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[scrollView]-0-|",options: [], metrics: nil,  views:viewBindingsDictBoth))

            view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[scrollView]-0-|",options: [], metrics: nil, views:viewBindingsDictBoth))

            view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[contentView]|",options: [], metrics: nil, views:viewBindingsDictBoth))
            view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[contentView]|",options: [], metrics: nil, views:viewBindingsDictBoth))

            view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[contentView(==mainView)]",options: [], metrics: nil, views:viewBindingsDictBoth))

           // self.view.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Redraw
        }
```